# How long has the LA office of the SSR been open?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agent-carter

Season 2 of *Agent Carter* picks up an undetermined amount of time after Season 1. Agent Sousa has gone to LA to open a west coast office for the SSR.

The office seems to generally be understaffed, as he requests assistance from the east coast office.

I initially felt like he hadn't been out there very long, but we learn that

> he has a new girlfriend, and they appear to live together.

**Prior to Season 2, how long has Agent Sousa been in California?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's been in Los Angeles for six months:

> **Detective Henry:** You ever hear of the Lady of the Lake killings?
>
> **Sousa:** Can't say I have.
>
> **Detective Henry:** How long have you been in L.A.?
>
> **Sousa:** Six months.
>
> <sup>*Agent Carter* Season 2 Episode 1: "The Lady in the Lake"</sup>

This doesn't preclude the possibility that he spent some more time tooling around in California, but it gives us a lower bound at least.

Comment: Sousa moves fast with the ladies.

Comment: @phantom42 The man is a fox; what can I say